# Is it possible to use random.choice( ) on nested loops?

Tags: python-3.x

`fruit_list = [['apple', 3], ['banana', 8], ['cherry', 5]]`

I was wondering if there is any way I could use .random to randomly generate from the choice of apple, banana or cherry from the nested list, and afterwards shows which item is chosen, while minus-ing off one from the count. (pardon my poor english)

`result: 'You got banana!'`
`fruit_list = [['apple', 3], ['banana', 7], ['cherry', 5]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
random.choice(list)
```

if want output first value of result type of list:

```
random.choice(list)[0]
```